# Function argument placement in C

Tags: c, function, syntax, function-definition

I am using the [SDBM](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html) hash function in a program and have a question regarding the function definition, reproduced below:

```
static unsigned long
sdbm(str)
unsigned char *str;
{
    unsigned long hash = 0;
    int c;

    while (c = *str++)
        hash = c + (hash << 6) + (hash << 16) - hash;

    return hash;
}
```

I understand by trial and error that the function is expecting an `unsigned char *`, but why place it after the brackets and before the curly brace? I didn't know this was an option, and I can't find anything to tell me why it's not written like this instead:

```
static unsigned long
sdbm(unsigned char *str)
{
    ....
}
```

Of course, if I do modify it to be like this, the function still appears to work perfectly well, so why do it? What's the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [K&R method of function definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#K.26R_style), nothing wrong, but obsolete. This was the way of function definition in pre-ISO era.

Technically,

```
static unsigned long
sdbm(str)
unsigned char *str;
{
```

is exactly same as

```
static unsigned long sdbm ( unsigned char *str ) {
```